# Error migrating OpenLaszlo app to 5.0: org.openlaszlo.sc.CompilerError / Overriding a function that is not marked for override

Tags: migration, openlaszlo, lzx

I have a rich text class present in OL 3.3 which i am converting to OL5.0 i used the incubator code present in 5.0 but when i am compiling it . I am getting this error. Any idea why this error is coming?

> [exec] org.openlaszlo.sc.CompilerError: extensions/views/richinputtext.lzx: 113: Error: Overriding a function that is not marked for override, in line: function updateData () {
>
> [exec] extensions/views/richinputtext.lzx: 182: Error: Overriding a function that is not marked for override, in line: function getText () {

Comment: I've modified the title of this question as well, and added the tags [tag:migratio] and [tag:lzx].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <richinputtext> component only works in the SWF8 runtime. The component was created for the old LaszloMail application. It does not work in either DHTML or ActionScript based runtimes like SWF10 or SWF11. For Webtop and the email client, Laszlo uses a [rich text editor](http://labs.openlaszlo.org/trunk-nightly/docs/developers/richtext.html), which is based on a Dojo framework component.

Comment: Which runtime are you targetting? For the SWF runtime, you could create your own rich text component, or even re-use an existing one based on the [Adobe Text Layout Framework (TLF)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/tlf.html). The TLF will be contributed to Apache Flex as well.

Comment: I am targetting swf 10 and DHTML

Comment: Then the only OpenLaszlo way of doing it is to embed the RTE editor in an iFrame. I don't know any open source implementation of a dual runtime RTE for OpenLaszlo 4.x.

Comment: I want to use one common rich text area for both DHTML and SWF. The Dojo Editor looks ok. Can i customize that ?

Comment: Ok.. I'll try like this itself.